# Using std::is_base_of with decltype on class hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11

For the purposes of brevity, this is the simplified hierarchy:

```
class IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IBase() = 0 { };
};  // eo IBase


class IDerived : public virtual IBase
{
public:
    virtual ~IDerived() = 0 { };
};  // eo IDerived

class Base : public virtual IBase
{
public:
    Base() { };
    virtual ~Base() { };
};  // eo Base


class Derived : public IDerived
              , public Base
{
};  // eo Derived
```

And a function to determine if a particular pointer to a class implements the passed "interface":

```
template<typename T>
bool same(IBase* base)
{
    if(std::is_base_of<T, decltype(*base)>::value)
        return true;
    return false;
};
```

And the sample:

```
IDerived* i(new Derived());
bool isSame = same<IDerived>(i);
```

I am aware I may me mis-using `decltype` here.  It appears whatever I try, `std::is_base_of<B,D>::value` is always `false`.  What I want this function to do is, answer the question:

**Does the object pointed to, derive from the type (`T`) passed as the template parameter?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`decltype`, like `sizeof`, is a compile-time construct. That means, `decltype(*base)` will give the *static* type of the expression `*base` which is `IBase`. So what you intend to achieve cannot be done this way.

I would suggest this solution:

```
template<typename T>
bool same(IBase* base)
{
     return dynamic_cast<T*>(base) != nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Thanks for this.  I was hoping to avoid using dynamic_cast.  But looks like it's the way to go for now.

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
bool same(IBase* base)
{
    if(std::is_base_of<T, decltype(*base)>::value)
```

This can't work. `decltype(*base)` would be `IBase` (always), so it would never reflect the runtime type of `base`.

Probably the best you can do is `dynamic_cast<T*>(base)!=0`.